# How do I call a python function from Javascript file in Odoo v8 in a newly created module?

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I have created a new module in `Odoo v8` and I want to call a python function defined in the controllers folder of the module from a JavaScript file defined in `static/src/js`.

I have tried the following:

1.

```
function openerp_pos_models(instance){

var myModel = new instance.web.Model('my.model'); 
//code to call python method
});
```

But on loading the page it shows `instance is not defined`.

2.

```
var Users = new openerp.web.Model('res.users');
```

but this shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Model' of undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your function calling into widgets.js file.

```
module.VisitorWidget = module.PosBaseWidget.extend({
    template: 'VisitorWidget',
    init: function(parent, options){
            options = options || {};
            this._super(parent, options);
            this.label   = options.label;
    },
    renderElement: function(){
        var self = this;
        var pos = self.pos;
        var shop = this.pos.get('shop');
        var counter = self.pos.get('visitorcounter');
        var visitors = self.pos.get('visitors',[])
        this.label = counter.toString();
        this._super();
        this.$el.click(function(){
            self.pos.set('visitorcounter', counter + 1);
            var date = new Date();
            obj = { 'visitdate' : date,
                    'count' : 1 ,
                    'shop_id' : shop.id,
            }
            self.pos.get('visitors',[]).push(obj);
            self.renderElement();
        });
    },
    sync_visitors:function(){
        var visitors = self.pos.get('visitors',[]);
        (new instance.web.Model('shop.visitor.history')).get_func('sync_visitors')(visitors)
            .fail(function(unused, event){
                event.preventDefault();
                return;
            })
            .done(function(){
                self.pos.set('visitors',[])
            });
    },
});
```

And this is my python function

def sync_visitors(self, cr, uid, visitors, context=None):
        if not visitors:
            return False

```
    for visitor in visitors:
        shop = visitor.get('shop_id',False)
        visitdate = visitor['visitdate']
        count = visitor['count']
        vals = {
                'visitdate' : visitdate,
                'count' : count,
                'shop_id' : shop,
        }
        self.create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)

    return True
```

And for same you need to create model into the models.js.

Comment: I want to call the python function for a new template and not the extended one, for the extended one the above code works. But when we create a new template in a new module and in JS file for that template, whenever making a reference to any odoo model it shows 'cannot call Model on undefined'.

Comment: then u use RPC method

Answer (score 2):

The problem is : it's not 'web' but 'website'
So now you have :

```
var Users = new openerp.website.Model('res.users');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my conroller route function(call in init file):

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request

class YourClassName(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/your/route/url_here', type='json', auth="user", website=True)
    def your_function_name(self, **kw):
        send_data = kw.get('data')

        // do something here.....

        //return data whatever you want to return....
        return data
```

Here is my js file:

```
odoo.define('igcc.export_view', function(require){
     "use strict"
    var core = require('web.core');
    var ajax = require('web.ajax');

    var QWeb = core.qweb;
    var _t = core._t;

    $('.button_name_here').click(function(){
        ajax.jsonRpc("/your/route/url_here", 'call', {'data':you_eant_to_send}).then(function (data) {
            //on successfully return data
        });
    }
});
```